# Integrate on a contour in the complex plane

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I want to integrate the function

`f[z]= z + Conjugate[z]`

over a circle of radius 2 centered at the origin.

For the sake of stating something that I have tried:

```
Integrate[z + Conjugate[z], {z, 1, I, -1, -I, 1}]
```

seems to give me the integral around the square with vertices `1, I, -1, -I`.  Also I can get the integral on a line segment with:

`Integrate[z + Conjugate[z], {z, 0, 1 + I}]`.

How do I integrate on a curve?

Comment: Let $z=2\exp(it)$...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First we shall define 'the integration on a curve'. Traditionally, this is defined as integration of f.dl where dl is the length of a small part of the curve.

So, using t as a medium, we can explicitly write out the curve's function on a complex plane, here let's assume it's `z=2 Exp[I t]`.

Then we can use t, a real number, as the integration variable, which make this problem significantly easier.

The final code is shown below:

```
z=2 Exp[I t];
f[z_]:=z+Conjugate[z];
Integrate[f[z] Abs[D[z,t]],{t,0,1}]
```

result is:

```
8 Sin[1]
```

Hope this answer is helpful to you:)

Comment: If on a contour, this problem can be quite difficult as not all the time the contour can be explicitly explained by functions. But I suppose your need is just what I've posted~:)

Comment: OK Thanks.  The result I am after is 8*Pi*I.  I can use your code but the definition of complex integration is different from what you have.  Also in order to integrate around the entire circle t must go from 0 to 2*Pi.   z=2 Exp[I t];
f[z_]:=z+Conjugate[z];
Integrate[f[z] D[z,t],{t,0,2*Pi}]

Comment: yeah，this code can be used in different situations, but you will need to change the function of the integration curve and the integration range.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

It can get more complicated. Look at a contour given by

```
r[t_] := 1 + 2 Cos[t];
```

**Original post**

The result of the integral for a (reasonable) closed contour is just 2 I times the area enclosed by the contour.

Proof: the integral is

$$\int \left(z^*+z\right) \, dz$$

Letting

$$z=x+i y$$,
$$dz=dx+i dy$$

the integral becomes

$$\int 2 x (dx + i dy)=2 i \int dy* x - 2 \int dx *x $$

It can be easily shown that the second summand vanishes over a closed curve which completes the proof. QED.